# What can you say about the smoothness of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I have a function $f$ defined on $]0,+\infty[$ such that: 
$$ \begin{cases} f(1)=0\\ \forall z \in ]0,1], \quad f(z) \in i\mathbb{R}\\ \forall z \in [1,+\infty[, \quad f(z) \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
$$

I also have the existence of a function $\Psi$ such that:
$$ \Psi \in \mathcal{C}^1([-1,+\infty[)\cap\mathcal{C}^2(]-1,+\infty[)
\;\text{and }$$
$$\forall z\in [-1,+\infty[ \;\Psi(z)=\int_1^{+ \infty}\mathrm{d}y\;f(y)\frac{z}{y}\frac{1}{y+z}$$
Is there anything we can say about f or its derivatives ?

I know an example of such f:
$$f(z)=[\ln z]^{3/2}$$

Comment: It can't be analytic at $1$. Hint for proof: how would the derivatives of all orders look like when approaching $1$ from, respectively, left or right?

Comment: How about $f\equiv 0?$